# Add method to a class which can only be accessed inside specific class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class in initializers in which I use Hash class and I would like to add 2 methods to Hash class. I know how to add methods to the class but I don't want to make the Hash class "dirty".

Is there a way that I can extend the Hash class with those two methods but only inside the class where I use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use refinements for this:

> Due to Ruby's open classes you can redefine or add functionality to existing classes. This is called a “monkey patch”. Unfortunately the scope of such changes is global. All users of the monkey-patched class see the same changes. This can cause unintended side-effects or breakage of programs.
>
> Refinements are designed to reduce the impact of monkey patching on other users of the monkey-patched class. Refinements provide a way to extend a class locally. Refinements can modify both classes and modules.

Something like this:

```
module HashPatches
  refine Hash do
    def new_hash_method
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

and then:

```
class YourClass
  using HashPatches

  def m
    {}.new_hash_method
  end
end
```

That would let you call `YourClass.new.m` (which would use `new_hash_method`) but it wouldn't pollute `Hash` globally so outside `YourClass`, `some_hash.new_hash_method` would be a `NoMethodError`.

Reading:

- [Official Refinements docs](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html)
- [Refinements spec](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-master/wiki/RefinementsSpec)

Comment: Just what I was looking for! I don't like to extend the standard Ruby classes for the reasons you mentioned. This works perfectly. Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 1):

A less hacky way could be to use `SimpleDelegator`.

```rb
class Foo
  class SuperHash < SimpleDelegator
    def new_method
      # do something with hash
      # you can use __getobj__() or super
    end
  end
  private_constant :SuperHash

  def initialize
    @hash = SuperHash.new({})
  end
end
```

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/SimpleDelegator.html